# Weird - Empty pd.dataframe after Excel import. But why?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm afraid I'll despair soon.
I am importing an Excel file, and this always worked in this way for me. But nowI am getting an empty dataframe, and I don't know why?

My demo code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel ('import.xlsx', sheet_name=["Sheet 1", "Sheet 2"], dtype=str)
print (data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Header A", "Header B"] , dtype=str)
print (df)
```

My excel file consists of two sheets, and each sheet looks like this:

```
| Header A | Header B |
|:--------:|:--------:|
| 1        | A        |
| 2        | B        |
| 3        | C        |
```

[image]

And this it the ouput:

```
{'Sheet 1':   Header A Header B
0        1        A
1        2        B
2        3        C, 'Sheet 2':   Header A Header B
0        1        A
1        2        B
2        3        C}
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

Import works well, because when I print the data dict the data is there. But the DataFrame is empty. I looked for white spaces in the column names, etc. Even if I import only one sheet, the dataframe remains empty. But why?

Comment: `data` is dictionary with all sheets in file and you should rather use `data["Sheet1"]` in `DataFrame(data["Sheet1"], ...` to load single sheet in dataframe. OR maybe you should even do directly `df = data["Sheet1"]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but it seems it gives dictionary with many dataframes and if you want to work with single sheet (single dataframe) then you should get it directly

```
df = data["Sheet1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the data to dataframe. The dictionary contains the dataframe as the value of key sheet 1 and sheet 2

To solve this problem: you can apply slicing from the dict using the key below

```
df = data['Sheet 1']
```

and then append the second sheet to dataframe as second column by slicing like

```
df['Header B'] = data['Sheet 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the output you want? (since both sheets are the same)

try:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("import.xlsx", sheet_name=None, dtype=str), ignore_index=False)
```

if you want this:

```
            Header A    Header B
Sheet1  0       1          A
        1       2          B
        2       3          C
Sheet2  0       1          A
        1       2          B
        2       3          C
```

or:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("import.xlsx", sheet_name=None, dtype=str), ignore_index=True)
```

if you want this:

```
    Header A    Header B
0      1           A
1      2           B
2      3           C
3      1           A
4      2           B
5      3           C
```

I used sheet_name=None since you said your excel file only consists of these two sheets.